# Dynamic select query in stored Procedure?

Tags: sql

My webform contain some checkboxes.If perticular checkbox is checked,add column name into select query of sp.Like 
Suppose there are 4 checkbox like chklname,chkfname,chkcity,chkmobile.If I check 
chklname and chkfname,my query will be :

```
SELECT LastName,FirstName FROM table1
```

How to write that in sp?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why don't you select all columns on your sql query then only display checked columns on your client ?

Comment: There is quite a number of ways to to that! What have you tried so far? How does your sp look like?

Comment: In code file,I handled.I have created string called strSelect.If(chklname.checked == true){strselect = 'lname''}If (chkfname.checked == true){ strselect = strselect +'firstname,'}.That strselect is passed to the sp as input para.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcName
    @chklname bit,
    @chkfname bit,
    @chkcity bit,
    @chkmobile bit
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Only execute the statement if at least one of the checkboxes are set
    if @chklname = 1 or @chkfname = 1 or @chkcity =1 or @chkmobile =1 
        begin
        declare @sqlcommand nvarchar(max) 


        set @sqlcommand = N'Select '

        if @chklname = 1
            set @sqlcommand += N'FirstName '

        if @chkfname = 1
        begin
            if len(@sqlcommand) > 1
                set @sqlcommand += N','
            set @sqlcommand += N'LastName '
        end
        if @chkcity = 1
        begin
            if len(@sqlcommand) > 1
                set @sqlcommand += N','
            set @sqlcommand += N'City '
        end
        if @chkmobile = 1
        begin
            if len(@sqlcommand) > 1
                set @sqlcommand += N','
            set @sqlcommand += N'Mobile '
        end

        set @sqlcommand += N' FROM table1'

        exec sp_executesql @statement = @sqlcommand

    end
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do here is handle the number of column names to be included in select through the front-end code.

Lets say for example out of 4 check boxes,use selects only 2 that fname and lname check boxes.

So in the front-end before formaing the sql select statement,you can decide which check box has been selected by user and which is not selected.Based on this you can form the proper select statement.